# Is it possible to set up email notifications in TeamCity for server health issues?

Tags: teamcity

How can I set up email notification to Administrator users whenever there is a server health issue on the TeamCity server (eg, when disk space is running low)?

Comment: Look for generic "low disk space" notifications on ServerFault

Comment: @OrangeDog, I don't want general low-disk notification for the entire server at the OS level, but rather that TeamCity itself has detected that there is some health issue (could be disk space or any of a slew of other issues). TeamCity already detects these things and notifies via its UI. I'm just looking for a way to get it to send email notification, too (like it does for build failures).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no such functionality, but several issues are at work: [TW-2795 with  related issues](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-2795) and [TW-27675](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-27675)